# Will wall anchors work when screwed into a stud?

Tags: walls, shelving, anchor, drywall-anchor

I'm installing some Lack floating shelves from IKEA. I have two holes into the drywall with anchors ([the metal kind with large threads](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/300/cd/cd04aab8-892c-4c02-b9af-0c7dbbf1cd98_300.jpg)), and one hole into the stud.

The problem is, I got confused and screwed a wall anchor into the wooden stud. I was pre-drilling holes for the anchors, so there's also a hole (larger than the screw) in the stud. The anchors say they are fine to use with wood, but what do you guys think? Do I need to back these out and start over, or will these hold my shelves like this? I am expecting the shelves to hold 20–30 lbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would remove them, however the anchor you are using is marketed as a "stud solver" meaning that it can be driven into a stud.  I think it is fine to leave them.

If you were using small plastic drywall anchors then I'd definitely remove them and drive a screw directly into the stud.

Comment: I use 'em and like 'em

Comment: @Steven. How do I remove the wall anchor? I can't just cut off the head and push the rest through cause there's a stud there and I can't pull it out cause it sits there very "sturdily" (for a lack of a better word). So how do you remove wall anchor if there's a stud behind the anchor?

Comment: If they are the type you install with a screwdriver, then just back them out (unscrew them).  Otherwise a pair of needle nose plyers and some muscle should get them out. Worst case bang them in a bit more with a hammer and put some drywall compound on top then re-paint.